# Python Script not creating file when run through Task Scheduler

Tags: python, csv, scheduled-tasks, task

[Link for python code running successfully through task scheduler](http://postimg.org/image/bio186409/)

[Image link for job detail on scheduler](http://postimg.org/image/79wt7xuz9/)

When running through job scheduler, python script is not creating file in script directory (Scraped data in csv files). TF-IDF is working perfect but I can't find files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably related to your environment.  What user is it running as?  You may try putting in a few lines to see where it *thinks* it is running.

```
import os

# Print current working directory 
print "Current working dir : %s" % os.getcwd()
```

or go one step further and actually change to the dir you want before processing begins.

```
# First go to the "/var/www/html" directory
os.chdir("/var/www/html" )
```

Comment: Are you explicitly setting the path to where you want your files to go?   If you run it manually does it work?  Also, since it is windows you may need to do some trickery with your paths.  I haven't written anything for a windows box for some time so I can't remember for sure but you may need to escape your backslash chars in your path.  A sample of  your code would help a lot.